# Displaying an image over another image along with transition

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-button

I have a welcome screen which displays an image using label as background.

Now, I want to and I'm trying to display an icon upon this background image with transition.

So, once the icon transition over the background image is done, I should be able to see the background image and the icon displayed in one screen.

Is it possible? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) using layered layout, I don't recall if we added it to LWUIT or later on as we forked to Codename One.

Failing that just set the image as the bgImage and then just place the other image on top.

Comment: thanks you @Shai. I was able to display welcome screen bg with transition.


bgImage = new BgImageForm(BlackImage);  
bgImage .show();  
bgImage.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(5000));  
bgImage = new BgImageForm(welcomeImage);  
bgImage .show();       

but the problem is now I want to display another image which contains some welcome text on top of my apps welcome screen(ws) once the ws fade in completes with the same fade in effect.  

Please let me know if this is possible or not and if yes then how can I achieve it in lwuit. Help me with SO code formatting also....

Comment: You need to accept the answer and ask a new question. These things are possible, check out the opening animation for the kitchensink demo.